# Sonar Quality Gate in Jenkins DSL API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I´m using Jenkins DSL to create my jobs, and I would like to use one of the sonar plugins to check the Quality gate that I configure in Sonar.
I´ve been checking in Jenkins DSL API but I cannot find anything.

Anybody knows if there´s an option in Jenkins DSL to add that option in my job?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Job DSL API does not support all plugins. Try to configure the job manually, then port the config to Job DSL. Use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to add any config not suppored by the API.

Comment: That’s exactly what I did to solve the issue. Thanks anyway. It’s the correct answer for people with same question that I had

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: Tomorrow I will

Comment: @paul instead of mentioning tomorrow, better mention friday. So that you can escape like you dont tell on which friday

Answer (score 0):

The following [configure block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) worked for me:

```
configure { project ->
  project / 'publishers' << 'org.quality.gates.jenkins.plugin.QGPublisher' {
    jobConfigData{
      projectKey('yourKey')
      sonarInstanceName('yourSonar')   
      buildStatus('UNSTABLE')             
    }  
    buildDecision{
      qualityGatesProvider{
        qualityGateResponseParser{}
        sonarHttpRequester(class: 'org.quality.gates.sonar.api61.SonarHttpRequester61')
        {
          logged('false')
        }
        sonarInstanceValidationService{}
      }
    }
    jobConfigurationService{}
    jobExecutionService{}
  }
}
```